# Probably Riemann surface integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-surfaces, spherical-coordinates

Here is the integral:
[image: Equation 1]

May you please suggest some beautiful idea on using Riemann surface, or some Gauss-Ostrogradsky at the beginning. Also, the initial integral looks really symmetric, so maybe there is some way to simplify form or switch to spherical coordinates...

And here are steps which I performed by myself:

By integrating over φ, this can be reduced to one variable integral:
[image: Equation 2]

Now I switch to complex plane:
[image: Equations 3-6]

Now poles (there are 4, all lying on real axis, 2 of them are inside contour |z|=1:
[image: Equations 7-10]

And suddenly, here comes sensation that there is root of polynomial, so there is branching at this points.

I've put this equation into Wolfram, but it returns something alienish:
[This integral on integrals.wolfram.com](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1/%28%281%20-%20a*cos%28x%29%29%5E2%20-%20b%5E2%29%5E%281/2%29&random=false).
Maybe it is possible to calculate all that limits at points θ=0 and θ=π. But there will be no way to prove that Mathematica solution, which is necessary for me :(

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: By the time, I did nothing by expanding that Mathematica formula containing ellyptic function F(i*inf|m) in taylor series around m=1, resulting in (pi/sqrt(1-(a+b)^2))*(1+ab/4+...)... Maybe it's still unsolvalble in elementary functions.